# How to draw a JMenuBar on top of a graphics

Tags: java, swing, timer, jmenubar

I am writing a basic timer program with Java, and in the program I would like to have a menu bar at the top. The code I have as of now is:

```
public Main() {
    JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();

    setJMenuBar(menubar);

    JMenu menu = new JMenu("Test");
    menubar.add(menu);

    JMenuItem menuitem = new JMenuItem("Item");
    menu.add(menuitem);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(500, 500);
    setTitle(Namer.name);
    new Timer(delay, timer).start();
    new Timer(1, new Refresher()).start();
    setResizable(false);
    setVisible(true);
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    Graphics buffer = unscreen.getGraphics();
    buffer.setColor(Color.white);
    buffer.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
    buffer.setColor(Color.black);
    buffer.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 25));
    // buffer.drawString("hours:minutes:seconds: ", 25, 100);
    buffer.drawString(hourss + numhours + ":" + minutess + numminutes + ":"
            + secondss + numseconds, 100, 100);
    g.drawImage(unscreen, 0, 0, null);
}
```

When I run this code, I get everything I would expect, which is some numbers showing how long the program has been up and a menu bar at the top of the screen, except the menu bar. I have tried commenting out the paint method, and when i do that it works. Is there a better way to do what I am doing or a different solution to my problem? Also, I don't need to have the paint method there if there is a better way to print stuff on the window.

Comment: have you tried calling `super.paint(g)` in your paint method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not a good idea to paint the JFrame directly. It may be less troublesome to extend a JComponent, override its paintComponent() to do your custom painting, and add it to the JFrame. This way the JMenuBar goes on the JFrame and everything works fine.

```
   public class DrawingSurface extends JComponent{

          public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics buffer = unscreen.getGraphics();
            buffer.setColor(Color.white);
            buffer.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
            buffer.setColor(Color.black);
            buffer.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 25));
            // buffer.drawString("hours:minutes:seconds: ", 25, 100);
            buffer.drawString(hourss + numhours + ":" + minutess + numminutes + ":"
             + secondss + numseconds, 100, 100);
            g.drawImage(unscreen, 0, 0, null);
         }
   }
```

Now you add an instance of DrawingSurface to the JFrame.

Comment: Also, drawing on the JFrame causes the first, lets say, 20 vertical pixels are under the title bar of the window.